# azure-cli-core 2.17.1 has requirement msrestazure>=0.6.3, but you'll have msrestazure 0.6.2 which is incompatible

Tags: azure, azure-cli, kali-linux

I have az cli installed on my Kali Linux. The `az --version` information shows an upgrade available as shown below.

```
kali@kali:~$ az --version
azure-cli                         2.16.0 *

core                              2.16.0 *
telemetry                          1.0.6

Extensions:
interactive                        0.4.4
azure-devops                      0.18.0

Python location '/usr/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/kali/.azure/cliextensions'
Extensions system directory '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure-cli-extensions'

Python (Linux) 3.9.1 (default, Dec  8 2020, 07:51:42) 
[GCC 10.2.0]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


You have 2 updates available. Consider updating your CLI installation with 'az upgrade'
```

However, `az upgrade` completes with `CLI upgrade failed or aborted.`
Logs show the following error.

> ERROR: azure-cli-core 2.17.1 has requirement msrestazure>=0.6.3, but
> you'll have msrestazure 0.6.2 which is incompatible.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`az upgrage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/update-azure-cli) is currently in preview and might have glitches. It is supported on Windows, macOS and some Linux distros. Not exactly sure about if the issue you have is related to Kali disro. But since Kali is debian based, just upgrade az cli using apt get. [Install the Azure CLI on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt).

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade -y azure-cli
```